# "[none]" value adding to the postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I am trying to add information from web site form, to the postgresql database and when I press submit button, email value write in database correctly but height value equal to [null]? 
Here is my python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres123@localhost:5433/height_collector'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "data"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_ = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height_ = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, email_, height_):
        self.email_ = email_
        self.heigth_ = height_


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/success", methods=['post'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form["email_name"]
        height = request.form["height_name"]
        print(email, height)
        try:
            data = Data(email, height)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            print('FILE')
        return render_template("success.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Here is my html tamplate:

```
        <form action="{{url_for('success')}}" method = "POST">
            <input title="Yor email will be safe with us" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="email" name="email_name" required><br>
            <input title="Yor data will be safe with us" placeholder="Enter your height in cm" type="number" name="height_name" min="50" max="300" required><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM3Ur.png)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your init method sets `self.heigth_`, not `self.height_`.